# Is there a way to avoid getting an error when I use one of two textboxes to search from database?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have two textboxes that I can use to search from database but it is not all the time when I use two textboxes to search.

Sometimes I use one but when i do so I get an error:

```
"Syntax error missing operator in query expression"
```

because the other textbox is empty. This only happens when I am using >=.
It seems to want all textboxes to have text.

```vb
    Sub search()
        Try
            DataGridRecords.Rows.Clear()
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * from tblDies where  `IDSIZE` >= " & txtIdSize.Text & " OR `ODSIZE` >= " & txtOdSize.Text & " ", conn)            
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read
                DataGridRecords.Rows.Add(dr.Item("ID"), dr.Item("DIENUMBER"), dr.Item("DESCRIPT"), dr.Item("OLDNUMBER"), dr.Item("CODE"), dr.Item("QUANTITY"), dr.Item("IDSIZE"), dr.Item("ODSIZE"), dr.Item("HEIGHT"), dr.Item("FLANGE HT"), dr.Item("FLANGE DIA"), dr.Item("CuRef"), dr.Item("CUTEL"), dr.Item("CuContact"), dr.Item("Price-selling"), dr.Item("P/no"), dr.Item("Stoksize"), dr.Item("Material"), dr.Item("Shore"), dr.Item("DieChkd"), dr.Item("DIECOST"), dr.Item("DATE"), dr.Item("REMARKS"), dr.Item("PRREF"))
            End While
            dr.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: *"In addition..."*. No. One question per question. If you have multiple question then submit multiple questions, each containing all and only the information relevant to that specific question.

Comment: You need to validate the user input, rather than just assuming it will be valid. Look at it to make sure there is input and that it is valid.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to insert values into SQL code. ALWAYS use parameters to avoid SQL injection and other issues. You can set the parameter value to NULL if there is no data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason why I did not validate the textboxes is because they are allowed to use either box to search or either of the two so now if I validate the textboxes I will be forcing them to use both/all textboxes.

Comment: *"I will be forcing them to use both"*. Only if you do it wrong. Validation is the act of making sure that the input is valid. If having input in either of two controls is valid then that's what you have to check for.

Comment: I don't see how this question is specifically about VB6 migration?